Combining Data From Multiple Worksheets In The Same Excel Workbook Using Power BI
I've trying to put file excel sheets in the same space in power BI. Essentially, I want to combine the sheets together in one.
I've been following a blog post and I end up getting a rather weird error. I've tried a couple things and I keep getting to the same error.
I tried using a different sheet, but I get the exact same error.
This is the blog post I've been following: https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2018/07/09/power-bi-combine-multiple-excel-worksheets/[![After all the steps, it shows the error of the different tables. Mind due]1]1


If you have to, you can use UNION, but I'd do this in PowerQuery. You can set all the other tables to not load and then do an Append in PowerQuery so that all the tables get effectively unioned together. Then you're sorted.
